# Update a particular field in ES 2.4.0 document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have document like this

```
               "College": "UCLA",
               "University": "American",
               "Branch": "MECH",
               "Name": {
                  "first": "john",
                  "middle": "william",
                  "last": "Richards"
                 }
```

I have to update the `last` field in `Name` group

I tried with the following but it is showing error

```
POST alma/matter/1/_update
{
  "doc": { "Name.last": "junior" }
}
```

Error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Field name [Name.last] cannot contain '.'"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Field name [Name.last] cannot contain '.'"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allowed to reference fields with dots in them. You can do it like this instead:

```
POST alma/matter/1/_update
{
  "doc": { "Name": {"last": "junior" }}
}
```

Comment: Thanks val..close the `last` field in your answer.

Comment: If i want to create a particular field in ES can i use the update API or i have to reindex the mappings

Comment: You can use the same call to create new fields, indeed.

Comment: So, then no need to reindex the whole mappings.Then when we need to reindex the mappings?

Comment: Well, a new field will be added to your mapping, but all existing documents won't have it for sure. You can then either use the update-by-query API to populate it or simply reindex all your data.

Comment: Thanks..val it helped